# CSS not loading in Chrome and Safari..works in Firefox and IE

Tags: asp.net, css, safari, loading

I am giving external css  path in aspx page via

```
<link rel="stylesheet" media="all" href="file:///D:/CSS/Style.css" type="text/css" />
```

its works fine in firefox and ie while access that page.

but when i open this page in chrome or safari.
it does'nt do anything and no css is applying.
please tell what wrong i am doing??.

Comment: I just tried your code locally, and it worked fine.  Could it be a user-permissions?  Have you  tried to paste that CSS path directly into Chrome?

Comment: Here's a general tip when it comes to web work: if you're linking to something, and it starts with `file://` (or `C:`/`D:`) *you're doing it wrong*.

Comment: Im with [True North Creative](http://stackoverflow.com/users/595602/true-north-creative) your code worked fine for me.

Answer (score 2):

Make a relative path in the `href` attribute. For example:  `"~/CSS/Style.css"`

Comment: my main concern is that if UNC path given my me is correct or not..its works in FF and IE but not in chrome.....jus tell me the correct HREf for my External css

Answer (score 0):

Try an alternitive way of linking to the css:

```
<style type="text/css"><!-- @import url(file:///D:/css/styles.css); --></style>
```

But also try running a local server rather than using the file system. [XXAMP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html) and [EasyPHP](http://www.easyphp.org/) are good.

Comment: It's ASP.net, so likely he/she is using visual studio which has a local server.

Comment: Ahhh okay fair play. Just trying to be constructive.

Comment: Everything else is fine for me. but do i give UNC path correctly....it works in FF and IE but why not in Chrome & Safari..

Comment: Looks fine to me and works for me. Thing to do is load the file in chrome and Safari and see what URL it gives.

Comment: when i open "inspect element" in chrome,.....it is hsowing.....""Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/CSS/KwizComStyle.css"".....can i change permissions settings in chrome...please tell me how

Comment: Try my [latest answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5065383/css-not-loading-in-chrome-and-safari-works-in-firefox-and-ie/5066169#answer-5066169), hope that works

Answer (score 0):

Done a bit of reading around, try using `"file://"` instead of `"file:///`" in your UNC. Chrome and safari should be able to read this and change it accordingly.

Comment: its not working sir......when i open "inspect element" in chrome,.....it is showing.....""Not allowed to load local resource: file:///D:/CSS/KwizComStyle.css"".....can i change permissions settings in chrome..